# "Any redirections associated with the shell function are performed when the function is executed."

Tags: bash, io-redirection, function

From bash manual

> Any redirections (see Section 3.6 [Redirections], page 31) associated
>   with the shell function are performed when the function is executed.

Where is a "redirection associated with the shell function" specified? Is it specified for a command inside the definition of the function, or for a call to the function?

Why does the quote emphasize that such a redirection is performed when the function is executed?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's simply saying that

   ` foo(){ echo bar; }>file`

won't create/truncate a file named file, and only when the function is called will the file be created/truncated.

Comment: do you mean that   running `foo` or `foo > file` will   create/truncate a file named file?

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell the statement in question means, as PSkocik suggested in a comment, that with `bar() { ... } > foo` you don't have to worry about `foo` getting overwritten until immediately before your function `bar()` begins executing. That is, just running a script that defines `bar` isn't enough to overwrite `foo`, you actually have to call `bar` :)

Practically speaking this also means that you can redirect with variables, `> "$foo"` not `> foo` because the variable will not be expanded/evaluated until function invocation.

Much discussion about this and other function redirection details can be found here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-bash-redirections